# Unable to make all UI components appear in RelativeLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I want a RelativeLayout based android UI that looks like the below mock graphic:
[image]

**Below is my layout xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayoutForPreview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <!--  surface view that contains camera preview , and seats above @+id/linearLayoutToolbar -->
    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surfaceViewBarcodeScanner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <!--  LinearLayout that contains toolbar that is divided into 3 sections horizontally -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/surfaceViewBarcodeScanner"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/scanner_bottom_left" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/scanner_bottom_center_toolbar" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/scanner_bottom_right_landscape_button" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I used Eclipse GUI palette and my own editing , however the output was not what I expected, the SurfaceView seems to covering all the screen, the LinearLayout at the bottom does not appear.

Snapshot of my current result on Galaxy S3 device:

[image]

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: wrap content for the surface view is the problem i think, try to give match parent for the surface view height and give alignparent bottom for the bottom linear layout and give toabove of this linear layout id to the surface view. then it will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try out to modify your layout as the follows:

- Define your SurfaceView and set it's layout_above value to the ID of the linear layout made in the previous step. Set the layout_alignParentTop to true.
- Define your bottom linear layout and set the layout_alignParentBottom to true.

Smart code snippet with only the important parts:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surfaceViewBarcodeScanner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayoutToolbar" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Linearlayout instead of Realtive Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surfaceViewBarcodeScanner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        >
<!--         inside elements  -->
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

else you should use  android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayoutToolbar" to your surfaceview
and remove android:layout_below attribute and add  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" to your toolbar view.

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutForPreview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <SurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/surfaceViewBarcodeScanner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/scanner_bottom_left" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="2">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/scanner_bottom_center_toolbar" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/scanner_bottom_right_landscape_button" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```